# Getting a specific old version of a package as a .sty file

Tags: packages, texlive, siunitx, latex3, dependencies

*The Problem*

I'm trying to submit a manuscript to a journal hosted on mc.manuscriptcentral.com, which, as far as I can tell, use a *very* old TexLive distribution. Naturally, this is out of my control. It's so old that I'm having trouble getting my paper to compile with siunitx: I don't remember having this issue with previous manuscripts now, but using it reveals lots of errors along the lines of

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \tl_length:N 
                        \l_siunitx_tmpa_tl 
l.272 ...sine pulse with a \SI{500}{\micro\second}
                                                   nutation frequency was ch...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

What I don't quite understand is that `\tl_length` appears to have been a macro in the experimental package latex-3 in `l3-kernel` that was removed from the distribution at some point in the past: on my local machine, if I do `cat /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/l3obsolete.txt` the relevant bit tells me so -- it was removed in January 2013.

So, I naïvely tried to proceed by uploading `siunitx.sty` from *my texlive distribution* to the journal's online web platform. This changes the error, at least, to something more human-friendly:

```
) (./siunitx.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 16, version
               `2015/09/11' of package expl3,
               but only version
               `2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper'
               is available.

Package: siunitx 2017/03/23 v2.7f A comprehensive (SI) units package

! Package siunitx Error: Support package expl3 too old.

See the siunitx package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

*The Question*

Ideally, I'd therefore like to be able to download a version of `siunitx.sty` from texlive ~2013   and upload it separately to the publishers' website.

Is there a simple way to easily find this, and download *just* this file using standard package management tools and free websites? (Moreover, any other insights are welcome!)

Comment: Why should you upload? don't they have a fitting siunitx in their system?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The one on their system doesn't compile -- it gives that latex3 error about `\tl_length` that I quoted above -- sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/releases?after=v2.4a but I agree with Ulrike, you shouldn't need this

Comment: well if they have a full texlive 2013 with a siunitx from 2013 and it doesn't compile, why do you believe it will compile if you upload a siunitx from 2013 manually?

Comment: Both very good points -- the closest thing I can find is a bug report (https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/228) to a specific version of siunitx that mentions that this error can occur if there is a version mismatch of the package, and that issue error message is substantially the same as in my paper's log. I hope that by putting a copy of the sty file in the path where my paper will be compiled, it will definitely be loaded preferentially. On my own distribution the code is fine (0 errors) and at the very least, iterating over versions seems a place to start? (Thank you v much!)

Comment: well as David wrote you can get older versions from the github. But imho it is the job of the journal to correct this (or to update to a newer texlive).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer – I totally agree. ScholarOne will get a vaugely snottily worded email from me, and I'm sure that Wiley will continue getting very, very rich. In the mean time, your suggestions worked. Please add them as answers so I can give you reputation.

Comment: Two years later, Wiley haven't fixed their submission system and the advice in these comments still work, albeit with siunitx version 2.6. One up side I suppose is that the journal _have_ released a "new" LaTeX class – https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/15222594/MRM%20LaTex%20Template-1651762116.zip – but this doesn't mention the problem at all, despite my emails!